# TFS 2010 Updated Start/Finish Dates not being published from MS Project 2010

Tags: tfs

We're encountering some publish/refresh issues with MS Project 2010 and TFS 2010. Our situation is that we're attempting to schedule and sequence tasks using MS Proejct (before the work actually gets underway). We have a Project Manager who is not on-site, and must work with a disconnected .mpp. When he makes changes, I receive the file, and then publish to TFS, and then refresh. For the most part, this is working okay. However, we've run into the following issue:

When our PM re-assigns resources, and then levels them in MS Project, and then I publish to TFS it appears that for a small number of tasks changes to their start/finish dates in MS Proejct are not being published to TFS. If I then refresh the .mpp file from TFS, following the publish, those same tasks in the .mpp revert back to the start/finish dates prior to the PM's updates.

From looking at the work item history for the affected tasks, it seems clear that it is a publish-issue....as there was no modification to the work item(s) start/finish dates recorded during the last publication. Manually fixing the start/finish dates in the MS Project task and publishing/refreshing works-around the issue...but that means we really need to scrutinize what happens in the project plan everytime we publish and then refresh.

I am totally stumped. This doesn't happen to all the task, and from one publication to the next, there is no apparent way to predict what task/work items will be affected.

Any help or guidance would be very-much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I can't confirm the following is an answer, but this is a hint for you:

After you bind a MS Project to a Team Project the file is modified in a way each task is linked to the corresponding Work Item, so if your PM still work with the initial file (not linked to TFS), the update part won't work the second time. You should give him back the modified version of the file that you made.

My concern is that I'm not sure he'll be able to edit this version if he can't connect to the TFS.

But you have to try anyway...